Crystal report A6 print issue in IIS
I have designed crystal report which needs to be print in A6 paper in visual studio 2019, from local host it is printing fine, but after deployment in IIS it is not printing properly. Could any one help on this.
out put of print is coming in center instead of full page
https://i.sstatic.net/DddCghn4.png

"it is not printing properly" is an extremely vague description. Explain properly what you have, what you expect and what you are getting

it is not taking full page, instead of it is coming in center

After deploying on IIS, the server's printer settings may be different from your local computer. Please check the server's default printer settings and make sure the paper size is set to A6.
Besides, If the server's default printer settings override the report settings, you may need to manually set the paper size in code. In C#, you can use the following code:
reportDocument.PrintOptions.PaperSize = CrystalDecisions.Shared.PaperSize.PaperA6;

